# PyQt - Linking multiple QTableView objects through scrollbars

Tags: python, pyqt

I have searched online but have been unable to find a solution this problem. I have three (although this can be any number) QTableView objects that are all longer than the size they are displaying (they are also equal length). For all 3 I have a scroll bar automatically generated. I would like clicking on any one of these to move the other QTableView objects by the same amount.

Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution for this online. The closest I got was this (https://forum.qt.io/topic/25139/solved-synchronizing-two-qtableview-s-scrollbars/3) although this did not help my situation.

Any help on this question would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a MCVE of three `QTableView` widgets with their vertical scrollbars linked. We connect the `move_other_scrollbars()` custom method to the `QAbstractSlider.valueChanged` signal of each scrollbar, using lambdas to pass the appropriate information: the `idx` of the scrollbars and the `scrollbar` that's been moved by the user). In turn, `move_other_scrollbars()` finds all the other scrollbars and updates their position with `QAbstractSlider.setValue(idx)`.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QStringListModel)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QTableView, QHBoxLayout)


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table_view_1 = QTableView()
        self.table_view_2 = QTableView()
        self.table_view_3 = QTableView()
        items = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cookies', 'drinks', 'eggs', 'flour', 'gatorade']
        items_2 = ['alligator', 'bear', 'cat', 'deer', 'elephant', 'flamingo', 'goose']
        items_3 = ['Arsenic', 'Boron', 'Carbon', 'Dysprosium', 'Europium', 'Flourine', 'Gold']
        self.model = QStringListModel(items)
        self.model_2 = QStringListModel(items_2)
        self.model_3 = QStringListModel(items_3)

        self.table_view_1.setModel(self.model)
        self.table_view_2.setModel(self.model)
        self.table_view_3.setModel(self.model_3)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.list_of_tables = [self.table_view_1,self.table_view_2, self.table_view_3]

        def move_other_scrollbars(idx,bar):
            scrollbars = {tbl.verticalScrollBar() for tbl in self.list_of_tables}
            scrollbars.remove(bar)
            for bar in scrollbars:
                bar.setValue(idx)

        for tbl in self.list_of_tables:
            scrollbar = tbl.verticalScrollBar()
            scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(lambda idx,bar=scrollbar: move_other_scrollbars(idx, bar))
            self.layout.addWidget(tbl)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

`QTableView` have two `ScrollBar` : `verticalScrollBar` ,`horizontalScrollBar`.
you can get this object with  `verticalScrollBar ()` ,`horizontalScrollBar()`,  the scroll bar object have `valueChanged` single this signal is emit when the scroll bar change position.
this code is a simple solution.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow , QTableView, QVBoxLayout,QWidget

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tab1 = QTableView(self)
        self.tab2 = QTableView(self)
        

        model1=QStringListModel([str(val) for val in range(0,100)])
        model2=QStringListModel([str(val) for val in range(100,200)])
        
        self.tab1.setModel(model1)
        self.tab2.setModel(model2)
        
        self.lyout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.lyout.addWidget(self.tab1)
        self.lyout.addWidget(self.tab2)
        
        
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        wid.setLayout(self.lyout)
        
        # connect the scroll bar signal to our slot
        self.tab1.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.__chnge_position)
        self.tab2.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.__chnge_position)
        
    def __chnge_position(self,index):
        # slot to change the scroll bar position of all tables
        self.tab1.verticalScrollBar().setValue(index)
        self.tab2.verticalScrollBar().setValue(index)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```